# Unexpected behaviour with strcpy and arrays

Tags: c, arrays

I am writing a simple string substitution function and I have a quite interesting error. Shouldn't strcpy just overwrite the buf\streamBuf value? How come it concatenates arrays?

```
int main()
{
    char buf[512];
    strcpy(buf, "Test\nInput\nHere\n");

    char fromCh[2] = "\n";
    char toCh[4] = "\\n ";
    stripChars(buf, fromCh, toCh);
    printf("Here's your buf: %s", buf);
    return 0;
}

void stripChars(char *streamBuf, char* fromCh, char *toCh){
        char strTemp[512];
        int i=0;
        int iLenFrom = strlen (fromCh);
        int iLenTo = strlen (toCh);
        while (*streamBuf)
        {
            if (strncmp (streamBuf, fromCh, iLenFrom) == 0)
            {
                strncpy (&(strTemp[i]), toCh, iLenTo);
                i += iLenTo;
                streamBuf += iLenFrom;
            }
            else
            {
                strTemp[i++] = *streamBuf;
                streamBuf++;
            }
        }
    strTemp[i] = '\0';
    strcpy(streamBuf, strTemp);

    printf("Here's your strTemp: %s \n", strTemp);
    printf("Here's your streamBuf: %s \n", streamBuf);
}
```

and here's my output

```
Here's your strTemp: Test\n Input\n Here\n  
Here's your streamBuf: Test\n Input\n Here\n  
Here's your buf: Test
Input
Here
Test\n Input\n Here\n 
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: the function: `stripChars()` is missing the needed prototype.  The prototype should be inserted near the top of the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How come it concatenates arrays?

That's because you are changing where `streamBuf` points to in the function.

Keep track of the original location of where `streamBuf` points to and use it at the end of the function.

```
void stripChars(char *streamBuf, char* fromCh, char *toCh)
{
   char* originalPointer = streamBuf;

   ...

   streamBuf = originalPointer;
   strcpy(streamBuf, strTemp);

   printf("Here's your strTemp: %s \n", strTemp);
   printf("Here's your streamBuf: %s \n", streamBuf);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here

```
streamBuf += iLenFrom;
```

and here

```
streamBuf++;
```

you change `streamBuf`

Consequently it will no longer be equal to `buf` in `main`.

So changes to data pointed to by `streamBuf` is no longer the same as changing data pointed to by `buf`

If you want to see what happens, you can add prints of the pointer values, like:

```
printf("buf is at %p\n", (void*)buf);
stripChars(buf, fromCh, toCh);
```

and

```
void stripChars(char *streamBuf, char* fromCh, char *toCh){
    printf("streamBuf is at %p\n", (void*)streamBuf);
    ....
    ....
    printf("streamBuf is at %p\n", (void*)streamBuf);
    printf("Here's your streamBuf: %s \n", streamBuf);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It was stupid of me not pay attention to it.